# Apex/Java Syntax unclear

Tags: apex, compile-error

I don't understand the syntax on the third and fourth row:

```
private void fsRespEmail(List < EmailMessage > newEmailList) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < newEmailList.size(); i++) {
        Boolean condition = newEmailList[i].Incoming == false;
        condition &= newEmailList[i].ParentId != null;
    }
}
```

On the third row, I understand that it creates a variable called 'condition' of type boolean and it assigns to it newEmailList[i].Incoming but then it checks if it's equals to false? It doesn't make sense to me.

On the fourth row, what does it even mean 'condition &=' ?

Comment: **Boolean a = ( c == d);** // a is true when c equals d.;   **a &= e;**// can be rewritten as a = a && e, so a will be true if and only if when a was true ,and e is true

Comment: Now it makes sense, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next structures are probably inherited from Java, as well as Apex is based on it.
First (third line of code) can be rewritten as next:

```
Boolean a = ( c == d);
```

**a** will be true if and only if  **c** equals **d**.

In the right side of the expression any boolean statement can be applied, in the same way as it is used in if statement.
Second (fourth line of code) can be rewritten as next:

```
a &= e;
```

It is basically same as  `a = a && e`, so **a** will be true if and only if when **a** was true , and **e** is true. That approach is often used in order to make code statement shorter, and do not repeat variable **a** twice.

More about salesforce assignment and boolean expressions can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)

Comment: `a &= e;` is equivalent to `a = a & b;` i.e. bitwise not logical. Will typically work with booleans but not a good thing to get into the habit of using.

Comment: @KeithC I thought that as well (have some c/c++ background) But in Apex by link mentioned above it clearly says  that a&=b is same as a == a&&b. I think problem here is slightly different. If b is a function, and a is false, it will be called in a&=b(); but will not be called in  a = a && b();

Comment: Yeah that documentation does say that the types need to be boolean as well so technically correct. But a coding pattern that is likely to confuse people and require double checking so not to be recommended in my view.